# Correct Qt version to build QGIS master

Tags: qgis, c++, qt, qgis-3

I just wonder wich version of QtCreator to install, current is Qt 5.11.1. Here I've read about building QGIS master with Qt 5.9.3 debug build: https://www.itopen.it/building-qgis-master-with-qt-5-9-3-debug-build/

So what would be the correct Qt version to build QGIS-master, or does any Qt > 5.9 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything >= 5.5 should work. But:

- there's major bugs in qt 5.6, so avoid that one
- QGIS 3D requires qt >= 5.9
- I'd suggest avoiding the very latest qt release, as occasionally there's build issues with the latest on QGIS which take some time to resolve.

So my suggestion (as of July 2018):. Qt 5.10.1